# ZK Framework Listbox Sorting not working with Dynamic Header?

Tags: sorting, listbox, zk

Hi i am showing Listbox header dynamically like this...

```
<listhead children="@load(vm.headerList)">
                <template name="children" var="headerName">
                    <listheader label="@load(headerName)"  ></listheader>
                </template>
            </listhead>
```

but when i am trying to add

```
sort="auto"
```

attribute in the listheader it is throwing exception .

Any one know how can i add sorting for dynamic headers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had wrote a simple code to simulate yours. But there isn't any exception.

http://zkfiddle.org/sample/2gsuhdf/3-Dynamic-List-Header-with-autosorting

Maybe the problem would be more clear if you provide reproducible code and the exception you got.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i made a component for Sorting with the help of Dualbox.Its a reusable component which can be used anywhere where anyone want to implement sorting and Listbox contain millions of records.